# What does WAN connection type PPPoE mean when it detects Static IP

Tags: wireless-networking, router, modem

On my router config page, under
Network>
WAN>
WAN Connection Type: PPPoE
is present by default.

There is a **detect** option next to it which provides Static IP as the result.

[image]

(the detect option in this image)

What does this mean? Should I change it? Will chnaging it, shut my internet access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can mean that your router is detecting a Static IP. Have you asked your ISP to provide you with a Static IP?

Also, what's your current configuration? And, are you facing issues while connecting to the internet?

As far as PPPoE is concerned, it stands for Point-to-Point-Protocol over Ethernet. PPPoE relies on two widely accepted standards: PPP and Ethernet. It is a specification for connecting the users on an Ethernet to the Internet through a common broadband medium, such as a single DSL line, wireless device or cable modem. All the users over the Ethernet share a common connection, so the Ethernet principles supporting multiple users in a LAN combine with the principles of PPP, which apply to serial connections.

I have the WAN connection type as PPPoE in my router configuration.

Comment: Right now its PPPoE and everything is working fine. But it detects Static. Should I chnage it? I am scared that it will shut it down.

Comment: @Edmund As long as it's working fine, don't change anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

static IP address assigned to a computer by an Internet service provider (ISP) to be its permanent address on the Internet. 
Computers use IP addresses to locate and talk to each other on the Internet, much the same way people use phone numbers to locate and talk to one another on the telephone.

[dynamic IP versus a static IP](https://superuser.com/questions/590391/why-do-isps-change-your-ip-address/590405#590405)